# Grasping the horns of the altar

Tags: reference-request, temple, 1-kings, altar

1 Kings 2:28-29 (NIV) says:

> <sup>28</sup> When the news reached Joab, who had conspired with Adonijah though not with Absalom, he fled to the tent of the LORD and took hold of the horns of the altar. <sup>29</sup> King Solomon was told that Joab had fled to the tent of the LORD and was beside the altar. Then Solomon ordered Benaiah son of Jehoiada, “Go, strike him down!”

How did Joab know he could do this? Is there a place in the Old Testament where it says a person could flee to the Temple, grab hold of the horns on the alter, and find safety?

Answer (score 1):

Joab possibly knew from an earlier incident of holding the horns of the altar by Joab's co-conspirator Adonijah whose life was spared by Solomon himself ([1 Kings 1:41-53](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+Kings+1%3A41-53&version=CSB)).  The basis for accused criminals seeking sanctuary could cling to the horns of the altar was not recorded, but alluded to:

- much earlier in Ex 21:14 which specifies that a man may be taken away from the altar if he is a deliberate murderer. Part of the purpose of 2 Samuel is to demonstrate that Joab was a deliberate murderer, so Solomon was acting legally in denying him that refuge.  (thanks to @StephenDisraeli's comment)
- much later in Amos 3:14 (see *GotQuestions* article [What was the significance of the horns of the altar](https://www.gotquestions.org/horns-of-the-altar.html)).

There are many things that Solomon-age Israelites knew that wasn't recorded by the author of Kings (see the "Sources used in Kings" section in this article [Introductory Issues in 1 Kings](https://enterthebible.org/courses/1-kings/lessons/introductory-issues-in-1-kings)), similar to there are many things that Jesus did that wasn't recorded (John 21:25)

Comment: It is also implied by Exodus ch21 v14, which specifies that a man may be taken away from the altar if he is a deliberate murderer. Part of the purpose of 2 Samuel is to demonstrate that Joab was a deliberate murderer, so Solomon was acting legally in denying him that refuge.

Comment: @StephenDisraeli Thanks for the comment.  I hope you don't mind I incorporated it verbatim into the answer.